# Api data returning null

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to use Jetpack in my Android development, I am able to display data from the the sports api but some of the data is null and not displaying, I am using data binding and this is was my first instinct check if null during my interview

`android:text="@{model.league != null ? model.league : @string/app}"`

During my interview however I failed I suppose due to not being able to identify what other location I can check for null data when the I display data. So my question is how do I change this code to ensure no textview is null or how do how I handle null api calls, and where, I just want to be able to not make the same mistake again.

```
Reponse Class

public LiveData<List<Match>> getEvents(String teamId) {

    final MutableLiveData<List<Match>> events = new MutableLiveData<>();

    Call<AppResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getEvents(teamId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AppResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<AppResponse> call, @NonNull  Response<AppResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                AppResponse appResponse = response.body();

                if (appResponse != null)
                    events.setValue(appResponse.getEvents());
            } else
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + response.errorBody());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<AppResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return events;
}
```

Comment: you can check for null data where you are trying to set the value to your textview.

Comment: @karan is that in the adapter?

Comment: where is the code that shows value in textview?

Comment: you can also check you event object before adding it to list that you are using to populate your data

Comment: @karan do you have an example of this? so what I did is check through data binding, and some code in the holder in the adapter class.

Comment: you should check how this line of code is working, `events.setValue(appResponse.getEvents());` you can switch this with a loop and check whether event object is null or not and only add if it isn't